# Angular template cache + bootstrap datepicker not activating on document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a single page application, using ngBoilerplate as a base for structure. I've installed bootstrap datepicker through bower and using it inline in my template file (which end up being compiled into javascript file as angular template cache modules).

```
 <div id="datepicker"></div>
```

All the javascript dependencies are loaded properly. Jquery first followed by Angular and all the rest. At the end of my index I have:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({todayHighlight: true, autoclose: true});
  });
</script>
```

Now after landing on index page and I navigate to the page which contains the datepicker div, it is empty, as if the init script never was executed. However when I do full refresh to the page then it will be executed and datepicker appears. What's causing this anomaly? If I move my datepicker div to the index then it always is initalised and works, but not on first initial load which uses cache templates.

[image]

Comment: use a directive to initialize jQuery plugins on elements. That way when element shows up, plugin will get initialized from the link function being invoked by angular

Comment: Right, thanks for reminding me, completely forgot that approach eventhough I recently just used exactly that on previous project, just thought I'd be able to have it more simplistic this time.

Comment: Why would the principles have changed?

Comment: I don't think it was just because of that, I had other problems related to modal instances and data binding through Java JSP tags and such in my last project that forced to go this way. This time I have lots of more different plugins that work perfectly when being initialized like that, datepicker became an exception.